# Modifying SharePoint KPI List views

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, kpi

I am trying to add new fields and a new view to the a SharePoint KPI List. The KPI List displays two views:

- All Items
- KPI List

I am not able to add or remove any fields that are displayed in these two views by default. When trying to create a new view it displays the four columns **Indicator, Goal, Value, Status** irrespective of what columns are set to be displayed by configuring the view.

While trying to add fields, a view and items with those fields set using code, it shows
this message in a red color:

> An error occured while retrieving
>   data.

Is this behavior by design?

Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: Having the same problem - really annoying this doesn't work. Anyone figure out a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like KPIs have a lot of bugs and limitations

- When you first create a KPI, it often doesn't pull the correct column list from the chosen view; inventing a fake KPI expression, saving it, and then editing it again will get it to update the column list. (Obviously a bug.)
- You can add new columns to a KPI list, but it won't display them or let you edit them. (Perhaps just incomplete implementation.)
- You can add filters to a view on a KPI list, but they are entirely ignored. (Obviously a bug.)